# Is there a standard, most common, or most neutral Spanish term for "chat room"?

Tags: traducción

Just earlier I was about to mention to somebody in Spanish that I was in a Stack Exchange chat room and I realized I didn't know how to say it in Spanish.

There's a bunch of words for "room":

- cuarto
- habitación
- sala
- salón

There's also at least a couple of words for "chat":

- charlar
- platicar

Of course a more formal word might be used for "chat" or even I suspect the word borrowed straight from English. **Which is the "best" way to express "chat room" in Spanish?**

---

There's now an applied equivalent of this question on meta: **[What should we call our "Chat Room"?](https://spanish.meta.stackexchange.com/q/108/157)**

Comment: I've heard *chatear* most often used to describe online chatting.  If I tell someone *estoy platicando*, they ask *¿por teléfono, o en linea?* But if I say *estoy chateando*, they know immediately. But I would guess that *chatear* is a Spanglish word, and likely most common in Mexico.

Comment: I thought I first spotted *chatear* in Central America and added it to Wiktionary but when I was looking for these words I didn't see it so I assumed I had imagined it and didn't include it in my question. Thanks for bringing it up! Aha [it is in Wiktionary after all](http://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/chatear#Spanish) - looks like I did pick it up in Honduras (-:

Comment: *Chatear* is used extensively in Latin America, so "salón de chat" is not uncommon.

Answer (score 5):

Chat room - **sala (de charla)**

*"Charlar"* is more used in Spain, *"platicar"* more used in Americas. More formal and neutral is *"conversar"*.

Comment: +1 I agree with sala or salón. They sometimes make a mix: "salón de chat"

Comment: *sala de conversación* gets ~170,000 Google hits, *sala de charla* gets ~1,710,000, and *sala de plática* gets ~387,000. But *sala de chat* gets a whopping ~13,000,000! All the variants with *salón* in place of *sala* exist but get a lot fewer hits.

Comment: well, most Spaniards just say "messenger" anyway ;-)

Comment: @vartec: "messenger" usually means a one-on-one conversation, not a chat room; at least in English, and in Mexican Spanish... is it understood differently in Spain?

Comment: As far as I know, the only country where "platicar" is widely used is Mexico.

Comment: @Filmzy: messenger, as Windows Live Messenger (f. MSN Messenger), it definitively had private groups, not sure about public ones.

Answer (score 5):

Here's what the *Diccionario panhispánico de dudas* says about [chat](http://buscon.rae.es/dpdI/SrvltGUIBusDPD?lema=chat):

> **chat**. Voz tomada del inglés chat (‘charla’), que significa ‘conversación
>   entre personas conectadas a Internet, mediante el intercambio de
>   mensajes electrónicos’ y, más frecuentemente, ‘servicio que permite
>   mantener este tipo de conversación’. Es voz masculina y su plural es
>   chats (→ plural, 1h): «Los españoles se conectan a los chats una media
>   de 6,3 días al mes» (Teknokultura [P. Rico] 8.01). Es anglicismo
>   asentado y admisible, aunque se han propuesto sustitutos como
>   cibercharla o ciberplática (→ ciber-). Está igualmente asentado el uso
>   del verbo derivado chatear, ‘mantener una conversación mediante el
>   intercambio de mensajes electrónicos’.

So the word **chat** is not only established but also accepted in Spanish (even though it has no entry in the DRAE) and it can be safely used.

To answer this question, the most common term to refer to a chat room would be

> *el chat* o también *sala de chat*.

and this can be verified by the number of Google hits. Of course, other expressions such as

> *sala de charla* o *sala de conversación*

are also valid, but *el chat* o *sala de chat* would certainly be the most common terms for "chat room".

Just as a note: until I searched the DPD for chat and found the above quoted entry (a total surprise to me, I must confess), I firmly believed that the word *chat* shouldn't be used in Spanish; now, my opinion obviously has changed. It's amazing how, thanks to questions like this one, I can learn new facts about my language everyday.

Comment: This is absolutely correct.  I can't stand saying _chat_ in Spanish, but regrettably it's what everyone says.  Worse still, now when I suggest _chateando_, instead of people suggesting good spots for wine, they start trading internet handles :-)

Answer (score 0):

Here at Spanish Language Beta SE, we now affectionately call our general chat room "La Tertulia."

Per [Wikipedia][1], **tertulia** means

> a social gathering with literary or artistic overtones, especially in Iberia or in Latin America. Tertulia also means an informal meeting of people to talk about current affairs, arts, etc.

More generically, I've seen people use "chat" to mean the place (chat room), for example

> Llevamos esto al Chat